# Swift UITableView AccessoryType (checkmark)

Tags: swift, uitableview, if-statement

I am using tableview accessory.Type (checkmark) in Tableview(didSelectRowAt:). When user click the row without checkmark, the checkmark will appear. When click the row with checkmark, the checkmark will disappear. Below is the code:

```
if cell?.accessoryType == .checkmark {
    cell?.accessoryType = .none
} else {
    cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
}
```

The above code is working as expected. When change to the following, it doesn’t work. Any idea?

```
if cell?.accessoryType == .none {
   cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
} else {
    cell?.accessoryType = .none
}
```

The code is as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    if cell?.accessoryType == .checkmark {
        cell?.accessoryType = .none
    } else {
        cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }

}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: When I click the row, nothing happen.

Comment: Put your code in some context. Show the whole method that this `if/else` is in.

Comment: Edit the original post and put the whole method at the bottom. I've just created a simple tableview with a few lines of records (using array) to test the checkmark. I used the 2nd group of code and it was not working, i.e. nothing happen when selected. After a while, i modified the code to the 1st group of code and it is working fine. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Change that to `if let` so you can remove all of those `?`. 2. Use the debugger and trace the path of the code and see what happens.

Comment: New to programming. Don't know how to use debugger. But I put the print statement. It seems that "cell.accessoryType == .none" return false.

Comment: What value is it? BTW - learning to use the debugger will make your life so much easier.

Comment: I put the print statement and it executed the print in else clause. i also put the code "cell?.accessoryType = .none" on top of the if/else statement, still the same. Thanks for the advice, definitely will learn to use the debugger.